# Legend using PathCollections

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, legend-properties

I'm plotting groups of circles using collections and I am not able to generate the legend of the three categories. I want:

- Cat 1: red circles
- Cat 2: blue circles
- Cat 3: yellow circles

```python
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import numpy as np

# (modified from one of the matplotlib gallery examples)
resolution = 50 # the number of vertices
N = 50
Na = 25
Nb = 10
x        = np.random.random(N)
y       = np.random.random(N)
radii   = 0.1*np.random.random(30)

xa       = np.random.random(Na)
ya       = np.random.random(Na)
radiia   = 0.1*np.random.random(50)


xb       = np.random.random(Nb)
yb       = np.random.random(Nb)
radiib   = 0.1*np.random.random(60)

patches = []
patchesa = []
patchesb = []
for x1,y1,r in zip(x, y, radii):
     circle = Circle((x1,y1), r)
     patches.append(circle)

for x1,y1,r in zip(xa, ya, radiia):
    circle = Circle((x1,y1), r)
    patchesa.append(circle)

for x1,y1,r in zip(xb, yb, radiib):
    circle = Circle((x1,y1), r)
    patchesb.append(circle)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

colors = 100*np.random.random(N)
p = PatchCollection(patches, cmap=matplotlib.cm.jet, alpha=0.4, label= "Cat 1", facecolor="red")
pa = PatchCollection(patchesa, cmap=matplotlib.cm.jet, alpha=0.3, label= "Cat 2", facecolor="blue")
pb = PatchCollection(patchesb, cmap=matplotlib.cm.jet, alpha=0.4, label= "Cat 3", facecolor="yellow")
#p.set_array(colors)
ax.add_collection(p)
ax.add_collection(pa)
ax.add_collection(pb)
ax.legend(loc = 2)
plt.colorbar(p)

print p.get_label()

plt.show()
```

`PathCollection`s are not iterable objects, so trying to generate the legend the following way;

```
legend([p, pa, pb], ["cat 1", "2 cat", "cat 3"])
```

does not work.

How can the caption to appear?

My system run on Python 2.7 and Matplotlib 1.2.0_1

Note that the command `print p.get_label()` shows that the object has an associated label, but matplotlib is unable to mount the legend.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#using-proxy-artist

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One possible solution is to add `Line2D` objects to use in the legend, also known as using proxy artists. To achieve this you have to add `from matplotlib.lines import Line2D` to your script, and then you can replace this code:

```
ax.legend(loc = 2)
plt.colorbar(p)

print p.get_label()
```

with this:

```
circ1 = Line2D([0], [0], linestyle="none", marker="o", alpha=0.4, markersize=10, markerfacecolor="red")
circ2 = Line2D([0], [0], linestyle="none", marker="o", alpha=0.3, markersize=10, markerfacecolor="blue")
circ3 = Line2D([0], [0], linestyle="none", marker="o", alpha=0.4, markersize=10, markerfacecolor="yellow")

plt.legend((circ1, circ2, circ3), ("Cat 1", "Cat 2", "Cat 3"), numpoints=1, loc="best")
```

[image]

Comment: Great.I was more concerned about finding a way to enable the legend, using patchcollections not thought of an easy way solve this my problem.

Comment: @Daeron If this solved your problem, please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so your question is marked as _solved_ for future reference, as well as providing us both with some reputation!