# Pandas Scatterplot Using Data Frame Fields to Derive Colors and Legend

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, visualization, scatter-plot

I want to create a scatterplot which shows two columns mapped against each other in pandas, a third for size, and then the color of the point based on the label (in the case below, last_name).

I then want a legend that shows a dot for the color and then the last_name value

Each last name should be associated with a different color and the legend shows, for example, a green dot and Miller, a red dot and Jacobson, etc.

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
    'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze'],
    'female': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73],
    'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
    'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'female', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])

plt.scatter(df.preTestScore, df.postTestScore, s=df.age, label=df.last_name)
plt.legend(loc='upper left', prop={'size':6}, bbox_to_anchor=(1,1),ncol=1)
```

And that gives me something like this:

[image]

I can't figure out how to get the colors in at all (ideally, I'd love to use a palette) or how to get the legend to show the last name and the dot

Any help would be much appreciated.. thanks!

Note - I am taking the example from here [Chris Albon](http://chrisalbon.com/python/matplotlib_scatterplot_from_pandas.html).

Comment: You can assign each point a different color with a list of colors: `['r', 'b', 'g', 'k', 'y']`. I'm not sure how to arrange the legend so that each one gets its own row but do not pass the label a series. You can do a loop and call scatterplot 5 different times and that will get you the desired plot.

Comment: There is actually a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614558/legend-using-pathcollections-in-matplotlib

Answer (score 5):

First, in order to produce colors, you can add a column with colors to your dataframe. Those colors can then be passed to the `c` keyword argument of `scatter`.

The usual solution for creating a legend with entries that are not easily accessible is to [generate proxy artists](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists). In this case one would create a set of markers of the different colors and provide it to the `handles` argument of `legend`. The legend labels are then simply the last_names from the dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines

raw_data = {'first_name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
    'last_name': ['Miller', 'Jacobson', 'Ali', 'Milner', 'Cooze'],
    'female': [0, 1, 1, 0, 1],
    'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73],
    'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
    'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70],
    'colors' : ["r", "g", "b", "k", "cyan"]} # add a column for colors
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, 
     columns = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'female', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore', "colors"])

#supply colors as argument for c
plt.scatter(df.preTestScore, df.postTestScore, s=df.age, c=df.colors) 
# generate proxy artists for legend
handles = [matplotlib.lines.Line2D([],[], marker="o", color=c, linestyle="none") for c in df.colors.values]
# supply proxy artists to handles and last names to labels
plt.legend(handles=handles, labels=list(df.last_name.values), 
           loc='upper left', prop={'size':6}, bbox_to_anchor=(1,1),ncol=1, numpoints=1)
plt.subplots_adjust(right=0.8)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A call to `scatter` will only make a legend entry. If you want a legend entry for each dot the easiest way is calling a plotting method for each dot. This should not be a problem performance-wise because you don't want thousands of entries in your legend. I will use `plot` because it works well for a dot but you could use `scatter` as well if you need fancier effects.

```
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    plt.plot(row.preTestScore, row.postTestScore, 'o', ms=np.sqrt(row.age),
             label=row.last_name)
plt.legend(loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1,1))
```

[image]

I didn't figure out (yet) how to make the dots in the legend the same size --and I am not sure that's what you want. I think different sizes look good and can help to locate people in the plot.

Alternatively you could use only one call to `scatter` and then examine the properties of the returned `PathCollection` and build the legend by hand, but I think my approach is cleaner.

Comment: In order to get the dots in the legend equally sized you can adjust the size of the handles in the legend like this `handles = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()[0]; 
[handle.set_markersize(10)  for handle in handles]; 
plt.legend(handles=handles)`